# TypeError using enumerate

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

Task: Given a list of movies in the cinema. Starting with index 0, each element in the array is the name of the movie in production on the i-th day. Transform this data by creating a dictionary schedule that for each movie as key stores the list of days when this movie screenings are. For example:

```
movies = ['Shrek', 'Snow White', 'Cars', 'Cars', 'Shrek', 'Shrek 2'] =>

schedule = {
    'Cars': [2, 3],
    'Shrek': [0, 4],
    'Shrek 2': [5],
    'Snow White': [1]}
```

Remember about case if movie is not in dict already.

Here's what I have so far, feel like I'm close...

```
# DO NOT change/shuffle the list
movies = ['Ice Age', 'Taxi', 'Taxi 2', 'The Star Wars', 'Taxi 2', 'Zootopia', 
'Zootopia', 'Taxi 2', 'Ice Age', 'Toys Story', 'Ice Age']
schedule = dict()

for day, movie in enumerate(movies):
  schedule.update({movie, day})
print(schedule)
```

Comment: Please show [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error messages when posting, after making your best attempt to [understand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) and [diagnose](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the problem yourself. Please also read [ask] and make sure to **ask a question** when posting. Use the title to *summarize your question*, not just to say that there was some kind of error. We generally need [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error messages, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```py
movies = ['Ice Age', 'Taxi', 'Taxi 2', 'The Star Wars', 'Taxi 2', 'Zootopia', 
'Zootopia', 'Taxi 2', 'Ice Age', 'Toys Story', 'Ice Age']
schedule = dict()

for day, movie in enumerate(movies):
  if not schedule.get(movie):
    schedule[movie] = [day]
    continue
  schedule[movie].append(day)
```

Comment: Initialize `schedule[movie] = []`, and you can drop the `continue` statement. Or, use `schedule = defaultdict(list)` and unconditionally call `schedule[movie].append(day)` without worrying about whether you've seen `movie` yet or not.

Answer (score 0):

movies = ['Ice Age', 'Taxi', 'Taxi 2', 'The Star Wars', 'Taxi 2', 'Zootopia', 'Zootopia', 'Taxi 2', 'Ice Age', 'Toys Story', 'Ice Age']
schedule = dict()

for days, movie in enumerate(movies):
if not schedule.get(movie):
schedule[movie] = [days]
else:
schedule[movie].append(days)
print(schedule)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).